# What is the most efficient way to use TNT?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

After months of curiosity I have finally caved (no pun intended) to trying out minecraft. I am currently trying to clear out a very large 25x25 area. I have built my first block of TNT and I'm ready to get down to buisness. I have read that enclosed in stone the explosion will create a 3x3x3 hole. However, what about *not* enclosed in stone? What is the proper hole size deep, and wide in order to maximize the blocks destroyed in a TNT blast? Assuming that all the sourrounding material is all basic stone.

Also possibly important to note: I don't care about any ore's destroyed in the process. I just want to make a **very** large dent in my project by blowing things up. Plus TNT is the manlier way to do it.

Comment: [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8415/3917) might help you out

Comment: The best way to use TNT is to use *loads* of it.

Comment: @fredley Unfourtunatley I don't have a lot of gunpowder at the moment :<

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's do some experiments!

I'm going to assume we're interested in making *square* holes, for several reasons:

- It's easier to measure and compare that way.
- You probably want flat walls.
- If you find a good blast pattern, you can do the same thing side-by-side to clear a larger area in multiples of the pattern without wasting any blast power.

I am also going to ignore the possibility of encountering a vein of dirt or gravel, which is much easier to blast and results in much less predictability of the results due to irregular obscured shape.

---

That 3×3×3 cube fact is true, but only if the TNT is actually fully encased — which would be a waste of time since you would have to light the TNT and then plug the hole. The way I have used TNT to dig is to make a 3-deep hole and place TNT at the bottom of it (or drop lit TNT down from the top, which requires less careful cursor work). *In addition* to blowing out the cube, it will also take out nearly all of the fourth layer above (say, with one block remaining). I have found this to be a very convenient strategy.

In this case, each TNT will blow up 3×3×4 - 3 - 1 = **32 blocks**, and **4 (11%)** were removed by hand.

---

Suppose we place a single TNT on a flat stone surface and ignite it. I did this and got a 7×1×7 hole where the outside was only partly exploded, leaving 12-15 blocks [3 trials].

7 × 7 - 14 = **35 blocks**, and you'll want to clear the remaining **14 (28%)** by hand since they're irregularly shaped so a blast would be wasteful.

---

How about the same as above but with the TNT inset into the ground by 1 block? That turns out to be the same as the first case without the blocks above, so it removes only 9+8 = **17 blocks**.

Let's go higher. Placing a TNT on top of some leaves (blast resistance = 1) results in another 7×7 pattern, but with only 9 blocks left unexploded.

Another block higher and there are many more blocks remaining; I'll stop here for now and assume this direction isn't useful.

---

So, the on-the-surface configuration blasts more area, but surely it wastes all that blast going sideways and upward. Let's try setting off a TNT in the center of a 3×3×4 hole produced by the first method (supporting the TNT with a block of leaves).

Whee! The second blast nearly perfectly enlarged the cube, leaving only 4 corner pieces. That means we destroyed 5×5×5 - 4 = **121 blocks**, or **60.5 per TNT**, with 3 + 4 = **7 blocks (6%)** to clear by hand.

A third TNT, supported 2 spaces above with 1 block of leaves, after clearing the irregularities, resulted in an irregular 7×7×6 hole with 52 blocks left in it, meaning 7×7×6 - 52 - 7 = **235 blocks** = **78.3̅ per TNT** were destroyed. This is an excellent efficiency, but notice that the amount of hand-work has gone up to **59 blocks (20%)**.

A fourth centered blast, after clearing the irregularities, only scarred the walls a bit; I'm not going to bother working out the numbers.

---

In conclusion, based on the patterns I've tried, the most efficient pattern (in terms of blocks exploded per block of TNT) is **three blasts at the same center point, starting with a 3-deep hole in the ground**, manually smoothing off the walls between each step.

(However, these tests were conducted in creative mode, so I did not concern myself with safety (i.e. getting out of the hole). The temporary stairs required to exit after the second and third setups may affect the patterns; or you could use a water stream or drop lit TNT from a frame above.)

On the other hand, if you want to minimize manual effort while making a square hole, then I recommend using two blasts, as that has the lowest manual work percentage while still being quite efficient in TNT.

---

My experimental setup was a flat stone surface with a surrounding 11×11 obsidian ring to aid counting and provide a height reference in case I blew up all the surface. Shown here is the situation immediately after the fourth blast discussed above.

[image]

Also, thanks for asking this question! I have learned an improvement to my own blasting technique.

Comment: Now THIS is the kind of answer I was looking for. Very nice application of science!

Comment: Thanks. Considered as practice of science, I'd note that it's a bit short on sample size (since TNT blasts are somewhat random but I ran most of the tests only once). I'm sure you'll take care of the *[replication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_(scientific_method\))* part, though!

Comment: Yeah, when I get out of work much damage will be done. I suspect I will die at least a few times in the process lol.

Comment: Stash your stuff in a chest, descend into the hole with just one TNT, eh? (Actually, a single blast won't harm your inventory when you die, even.)

Comment: No matter how cautious I am in this game I always manage to plunge thousands of feet to my doom, or get blown to bits by a creeper.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://minecraft.wiki/w/TNT

On this page, it says:

> Thus, the explosion propagates farthest (7 blocks) through air, which has a blast resistance of zero.

Also: This wiki has a page for every kind of block, and on them, each block's blast resistance is listed below the picture of the block. Hope that helped!